# Why is the Northern Hemisphere warming faster than the Southern Hemisphere?

Tags: climate-change, atmosphere

Hi I just found the NOAA table. It clearly shows that the N. hemisphere has warmed much more than the southern hemisphere since 1880!

[image]
https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/monthly-report/global/202113

What could be the reason for this?
My idea is that the N. hemisphere has accumulated significantly more continental mass, while the S. hemisphere is almost continent-free. And the water is warming because the Gulf Stream is currently flushing more warm water northwards. Is my idea correct? Do you have other suggestions or are there suitable papers?

Comment: this may be helpful, https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/sesj/26/4/26_374/_pdf#:~:text=e%20atmospheric%20carbon%20dioxide%20(CO2,understanding%20of%20the%20carbon%20cycle.

Comment: @Hexenbrei, thanks for your bounty!

Comment: Consider that there a a lot more land in the northern hemisphere and land usage change is a contributor.

Comment: One small comment, the Gulf Stream is in fact likely slowing down, so less warm water will be moving northward. https://www.severe-weather.eu/global-weather/gulf-stream-amoc-circulation-collapse-freshwater-imbalance-usa-europe-fa/

Comment: This Question is very interesting, my theory for the cause is that, Yes your theory applies to, with less/more landmass on either hemisphere, but I also believe land usage and the prevelance of factories and other factors can play a role in pumping more greenhouse gases into the atmosphere, many cities are located in Europe/Russia/US etc. Currents would also play a role. I'm not sure if this combination of factors would lead to a definitive answer.

Comment: Plenty of 'reasons' if you Google https://www.google.com/search?q=warming+northern+southern+hemisphere, but it takes further reading to get actual numbers. I don't have time to dig into all that and write an answer.

Comment: The difference between Northern and Southern Hemispheres in air pollution levels (which tend to "mask" warming trends), and their subsequent reduction in recent decades (which respectively "unmask" the actual levels of greenhouse warming) may also play a role. See e.g. Figure 4 in https://wires.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wcc.372

Answer (score -2):

The Northern Hemisphere is warmer than the Southern Hemisphere in part because of northward cross-equatorial ocean heat transport. http://ocp.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/div/ocp/pub/seager/Kang_Seager_subm.pdf

It is considered that the northern hemisphere has more land mass while the southern hemisphere has more ocean and therefore varies in the rate of warming.
https://atmosphere.copernicus.eu/carbon-dioxide-levels-are-rising-it-really-simple

Comment: Not to be harsh, but the question wasn't about which hemisphere is warmer (but about which is showing more additional warming of recent) (even as the reasoning/paper seem interesting).  And your second paper doesn't really touch on warming at all.  So doesn't seem you really addressed the question particularly with any more info, despite some interesting stuff overall.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest we must have had this question before in some shape or form.

Comment: The original question?  I can't find another (note that this one is 6 months old, Daria was just adding a new answer).  As far as regarding CO2 levels as Daria's second paper, it is the topic of [Why is there a seasonal cycle to the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/why-is-there-a-seasonal-cycle-to-the-amount-of-co2-in-the-atmosphere/3093#3093)